# 403 Error: Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource

Tags: articles

I have been contracted to manage a website built with Joomla, I have to update articles but anytime I try to save changes this is the error I get.

***Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.***

how do I solve this?.

Comment: Welcome to JSE.  Please take our [tour] to understand how our community works.  If you haven't yet had a read of [ask], please read that whole page too.

Answer (score 1):

According to a forum post in Joomla (link below), you could check to see if the Session Path Writable is set to NO. If the Session Path Writable is set to no, you will need to contact your hosting provider to change this.

Her is a link to a thread for the same problem: https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=971335